# How to remove visualization of blank sublevel in slicers

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, measure

I wuold like to know whether there is a way in Power BI to exclude visualization of each sublevel in the slicer you can see on the right of picture. I am just interested to remove the Blank sublevel, eventhough in the respective column of the table on the rught the column is empty. Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting each one to `is not blank` in the Filter pane for that slicer/visual?

Comment: Yes I have tried but unfortunatey it shrinks options just to those that have the entire sets of columns full. I was thinking to split datset and use relationship but unfortuately I cannot merge different object from different tables (since I got a many-to-many relationship). Do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as a ragged hierarchy. To fix, you can use a custom slicer which supports ragged hierarchies (e.g. https://xviz.com/blogs/ten-reasons-to-use-hierarchy-filter-slicer-power-bi-dashboard/) or implement some very complex DAX to suppress them: https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/

Comment: Thank you so much. Actuallly the filter that I was using is exactly that one. I just imagined but I did not know exacty how to implemented that option. Thanks